Find value of $\theta$ from an expression of $\sin\theta$ involving several terms
My expression for $\sin\theta$ reads $$\sin\theta = bx + \frac{2ac}{b^2} $$. And the resulting expression for $\theta$ is $$\theta = \sin^{-1}(bx) + \frac{2ac}{b^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-b^2x^2}} $$. Now it seems that the term with linear dependency on x is simply the expected $\sin^{-1}(bx)$ whereas the remaining term is multiplied by differentiation of $\sin^{-1}(bx)$ $$\frac{d}{dx}\sin^{-1}(bx) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-b^2x^2}}$$. No details are given in the text I am working through regarding any expansion or assumptions regarding how to get the said result. I have no idea regarding what exactly is going on over here. Could someone please explain the stuff going on over here.

First thought: Maybe it's some kind of approximation using linear extrapolation? So we'd assume that $\frac{2ac}{b^2}$ is small compared to $bx$ and then use the idea that $f(x+h) \approx f(x) + hf'(x)$. Here $f=\sin^{-1}(x)$ and $h=\frac{2ac}{b^2}$.

As @Matti P.  commented, if $\beta\ll \alpha$ then, by Taylor $$\sin ^{-1}(\alpha +\beta )=\sin ^{-1}(\alpha )+\frac{\beta
}{\sqrt{1-\alpha ^2}}+\frac{\alpha
\beta ^2}{2 \left(1-\alpha
^2\right)^{3/2}}+O\left(\beta
^3\right)$$

Can you provide the source for this? As written it's quite odd.

Thanks @Matti P., I think that seems to be the most likely explanation.

Thanks @ClaudeLeibovici that cleared things up for me.

@MattiP. in a very similar expression I have an extra $d\sin^2\theta$ term added  in the rhs of the expression for $\sin\theta$ and the answer for $\theta$ now reads $\theta = \sin^{-1}(bx) + \frac{2ac}{b^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-b^2x^2}} +  d(b^2x^2)\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-b^2x^2}}$ . Taking a quadratic equation in terms of $\sin\theta$ does not provide the answer and it seems that they are taking $\sin^2\theta$ term as negligible and doing the same taylor expansion and replacing $\theta$ with the value $f(x) = \sin^{-1}(bx)$ . Is the mathematical logic correct in my analysis?

@Semiclassical Sorry for the delayed reply. Its in a collection of previous year problems in mathematical physics course.

@ClaudeLeibovici could please also take a look at my query two terms above.

@Argentum. This is the concept of Taylor series. iT works if $\beta \ll \alpha$ in my comments. Suppose $\alpha=\frac 12$ and $\beta=\frac 1 {10}$, using what I wrote in comments gives $$\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)=\frac{\pi }{6}+\frac{1}{5 \sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{150 \sqrt{3}}$$ which is in an absolute error of $5.83\times 10^{-4}$.

@ClaudeLeibovici I get that. But if $\beta$ includes a term $\sin^2\alpha$ then is the expansion still allowed? and if so then how do we get rid of the $\sin^2\alpha$ term in the final result?

am I misreading the question? because the right hand side does not contain $theta$, you can simply write $\theta = \arcsin(bx + \frac{2ac}{b^2})$
